# Can MuseScore be used programmatically?

Tags: musescore

I wasn't sure whether to post this on StackOverflow or here, but since the pros in MuseScore should be on this platform, here it goes:

I have a custom build system to create a pdf songbook using LaTeX and I want to include tablature there. I parse ASCII tablatures myself and just need to render them.

So my idea would be:

I export the tablature to a format that MuseScore can read (XML?), then call MuseScore from the command line to render it as a PDF or image, which I then include in my LaTeX page.

Does MuseScore support this?

Comment: As you're already using latex, are you aware of [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/examples.html#Tablature)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MuseScore supports MusicXml, so if you can export to that, you're good.

According to [the command line options of MuseScore](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options), you can use the "-o" options to specify an output format, and it even has an [example](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options#EXAMPLES) specifying input and output.

How to include it in your LaTeX page is of course beyond MuseScore, that's up to you.

Answer (score 18):

Another option (if this could be allowed as an answer) is to read the XML in LilyPond, perhaps via [musicxml2ly](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/invoking-musicxml2ly).

Since LaTeX and LilyPond can work relatively well together, you may have better luck that way. And done the right way (like with [the `lyluatex` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/lyluatex?lang=en)) you could bypass creating the "output" altogether and have it immediately created in your file.

Comment: Seconded. MuseScore is first and foremost designed to be used graphically, LilyPond programmatically.

Comment: This sounds like the better option, +1. 
LilyPond seems to be designed for these kind of scenario's.